# Mac OS X, Objective C: Schedule daily method execution

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to find a means of scheduling a method call on a daily interval at a specified time. For example, every morning at 3am.

`NSTimer` and similar functionality is provided that allows you to schedule tasks after a specified duration but it would be nice if there is a way to schedule at a time, rather than after a time period expires.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's always nice to look through class docs before asking a question on Stack Overflow. NSTimer documentation says there's a method:

```
- (id)initWithFireDate:(NSDate *)date interval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

Let the `date` be the next morning 3am and the time interval - 24hrs.

Comment: You have no idea how many times I looked through there, can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Note that a better solution would likely be to use a helper tool that is launched via launchd.   That way, the app doesn't actually have to be running and it'll still work if the user quits the app.